# Rails add id to each option for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a bootstrap drop down menu in one of my Rails app forms that is populated with data from another DB, it works great except I want each option for select have its own id based on each classroom .... this is the code for the dropdown

```
<%= f.select :class_name, @classrooms.all.collect {|a| [a.class_name, a.class_name]},
    {include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control" } %>
```

And this is what it shows up as HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="teacher[class_name]" id="teacher_class_name">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Infant 1">Infant 1</option>
 <option value="Infant 2">Infant 2</option>
</select>
```

I want each option to have the ID for example 1,2,3 etc.. any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<%= f.select :class_name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control" } do %>
  <% @classrooms.all.each do |classroom| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, classroom.name, {:value => classroom.name, :id => classroom.id}) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```